# Gears shifter kinda working

Tags: gears

On my bike for some reason [when changing gear] it some times skips a gear and stays on a gear I'm not wanting to be on.

If you can help me please do so.

Comment: Hello - we need a bit more info to advise you better.  If possible, please add a clean, clear and well-lit photo of the cassette from the side and from the rear.   You can add up to two photos using the Edit link just below your question

Comment: 1) How old is the bike?   How much riding has been done on it since the last time the rear cogs were changed?

Comment: 2) when was the cassette last cleaned?  Can you scrape oily dirt out from between the cogs?

Comment: 3) if you identify which gear cable activates the rear derailleur, can you pull it by hand to make the shift better?   Could be that the silvery inner cable has stretched subtly over time.

Comment: The derailer needs to be cleaned and lubed, the cables lubed (unless the newer plastic coated style) and the setup needs to be adjusted.  Pretty much like taking your car in for a tuneup.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that can cause that:

1. The cable needs to be adjusted either at the derailleur or at an adjustment on the cable. This is the most common cause.
2. The chain, cable, and/or derailleur may need to be lubricated.
3. The chain my be worn out (stretched). You can check it with a special tool, at a bike shop, or by seeing how much you can pull off the large sprocket.
4. The cassette (rear sprocket) may be worn or have teeth missing.
5. There may be a problem with the cable routing, or maybe it's about to break. Make sure then ends of the cable guides are in their proper place.
6. As Argenti mentioned, the derailleur or derailleur hanger may be bent.

Comment: Bent derailleur hanger can be added to that list. As you say, most likely indexing needs to be adjusted though.